# Memory problems with table in R

Tags: r, memory, count

I need to make frequency tables from a series of large-ish vectors (in fact columns of data frames, but I don't think this is relevant) in **R.** When I run `table()`, memory usage steadily climbs until the system runs out memory, **R** crashes and restarts (at 16gb). The vectors themselves are quite large (5.9m obs), but clearly nowhere near 16gb - I don't quite understand why `table()` uses so much memory. I've tried `bigtabulate()` from the bigtable package, and `count()` from plyr, but there's no difference. I wrote my own little function (below), but it's incredibly slow. Is there a different way of doing this that's faster than my crude attempt but doesn't use as much memory as `table()` or `count()`?

```
level_counts<-function(v){
    df<-data.frame(value=levels(v));
    df$count<-apply(df,1,function(x){
        return(length(v[which(v==x)]));
    });
    return(df);
}
```

Comment: You could split your data.frame, then `table(...)` each split iteratively, then aggregate table results

Comment: were you by chance running `table()` on all the columns of interest instead of each column (vector) at a time?

Comment: @Cpak thanks, I'll try this

Comment: @RolandASc I've checked, and definitely not! same result from cur_col<-df$col; result<-table(cur_col) as with result<-table(df$col),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create an example vector and run `table`. This represents the standard

```
set.seed(1)
# this works with 16 GB
V <- sample(1:100, 6e6, replace=TRUE)
table(V)

# V
    # 1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12    13 
# 59851 60360 60662 60097 59978 59894 60252 60106 60075 59636 59926 60069 60007 
   # 14    15    16    17    18    19    20    21    22    23    24    25    26 
# 59576 60052 59912 59804 59861 59737 59903 60055 59877 60259 60090 59856 60660 
   # 27    28    29    30    31    32    33    34    35    36    37    38    39 
# 60157 60137 59653 60323 59649 60017 59616 60060 60004 60116 60157 60360 59860 
   # 40    41    42    43    44    45    46    47    48    49    50    51    52 
# 59957 59892 59813 59986 60009 60457 59875 59464 59806 60302 60002 59938 60079 
   # 53    54    55    56    57    58    59    60    61    62    63    64    65 
# 59876 59940 60059 60245 59949 60089 59942 60001 59973 60661 60157 60210 60189 
   # 66    67    68    69    70    71    72    73    74    75    76    77    78 
# 59770 59948 60333 59601 60353 59344 60089 60316 59529 59617 59694 59969 59790 
   # 79    80    81    82    83    84    85    86    87    88    89    90    91 
# 59743 60141 59975 59990 59658 60147 60389 60472 60111 60094 60102 60050 59612 
   # 92    93    94    95    96    97    98    99   100 
# 59911 60022 60228 59780 60153 59691 60041 59992 59810
```

Try the following to split your data and aggregate list-of-table results

```
L <- split(V, rep(1:10, each=(6e6/10)))
# you could use as well:  cut(V, breaks=10)
# in place of rep(...)

Ts <- lapply(L, table)  # table of each split

# merge results
merge_tables <- function(L) {
    require(dplyr)
    DF <- do.call(rbind, lapply(L, data.frame))
    ans <- DF %>%
           group_by(Var1) %>%
           summarise(Freq = sum(Freq))
    return(ans) 
}
merge_tables(Ts)

# A tibble: 100 x 2
   # Var1    Freq
   # <fctr> <int>
 # 1 1      59851
 # 2 2      60360
 # 3 3      60662
 # 4 4      60097
 # 5 5      59978
 # 6 6      59894
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're dealing with a `data.frame`, you can just loop across the columns and use `tabulate()` instead of `table()`. `tabulate()` is generally considerably faster. Since you're mentioning that you're running into memory problems, you can just use a simple `for` loop.

Here's an example of a 100 column `data.frame` with 5.9 million rows.

```
set.seed(1)
mydf <- data.frame(replicate(100, sample(100, 59e5, TRUE, prob = (1 / 1:100)/sum(1/1:100))))
```

Create an empty vector with the number of expected unique values. Here, I've hard-coded it as 100, but you can efficiently find this out in different ways.

```
x <- vector(mode = "integer", length = 100)
```

Use a `for` loop along with `tabulate`, adding the values to your vector on each iteration.

```
for (i in seq_along(mydf)) {
  a <- tabulate(mydf[[i]], nbins = 100)
  x <- x + a
}
```

Here's the result:

```
x
 #  [1] 113728224  56869605  37921007  28438216  22749305  18957822  16246750  14217145  12635554  11371434
 # [11]  10336993   9476935   8754409   8127218   7580889   7108428   6688372   6318092   5988240   5685836
 # [21]   5420640   5167806   4949677   4742169   4552045   4375381   4213460   4062181   3918424   3791238
 # [31]   3667651   3554914   3444016   3343632   3248479   3157525   3073123   2993397   2914555   2843628
 # [41]   2773669   2709270   2647620   2582847   2524157   2476936   2418578   2367692   2322076   2274352
 # [51]   2229395   2187669   2148847   2107710   2068427   2030564   1996654   1962316   1927702   1894340
 # [61]   1863165   1834852   1807164   1776901   1747323   1722719   1694721   1672816   1646864   1623807
 # [71]   1602506   1579049   1556790   1535832   1517130   1495177   1476688   1457067   1437976   1421363
 # [81]   1404197   1386446   1372361   1354048   1338653   1321241   1308175   1292688   1278896   1264299
 # [91]   1249357   1237313   1222000   1210713   1198957   1186282   1172569   1161049   1148689   1136921
```

You can use `setNames(x, 1:100)` if you want a named vector as the result.

---

Test it for performance. This time, I've not hard-coded the expected vector length:

```
myfun <- function(mydf) {
  maxint <- max(vapply(mydf, max, 1L))
  x <- vector(mode = "integer", length = maxint)
  for (i in seq_along(mydf)) {
    a <- tabulate(mydf[[i]], nbins = maxint)
    x <- x + a
  }
  x
}
system.time(myfun(mydf))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   1.200   0.000   1.201
```

---

Compare with CPak's approach, which uses `table` instead.

```
# merge results
merge_tables <- function(L) {
  require(dplyr)
  DF <- do.call(rbind, lapply(L, data.frame))
  ans <- DF %>%
    group_by(Var1) %>%
    summarise(Freq = sum(Freq))
  return(ans) 
}

cPakFun <- function(mydf) {
  Ts <- lapply(mydf, table)  # table of each split
  merge_tables(Ts)
}
system.time(cPakFun(mydf))
#    user  system elapsed 
# 150.937   1.041 152.872
```